# autocomplete ='off' is not working when the input type is password and make the input field above it to enable autocomplete

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have an form with autocomplete disabled but it does not works and makes the autocomplete to be enabled in firefox and higher version of chrome

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
    <ul class="field-set">
    <li>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="acct" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" >
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" id="Login" name="Login">
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

When the type is changed from password to text it works in all browser. 
Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Comment: To clarify: I suppose you are talking about the password manager, since browsers don't auto-complete password fields.

Comment: No Alvaro. you can see here that I have made autocomplete disabled for the whole form but the dropdown is shown in the input text field which is before the input type password(as in code).

Comment: That *is* the password manager. In my experience, disabling auto-complete prevents the browser from prompting to store the username+password but it won't make it forget existing passwords.

Comment: Thank you I got it. But when I execute the above form, the dropdown is not shown in chrome version 24, whereas I am able to see the stored username+password in FF 18. Is this browser issue? Is there any way to delete the existing password?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the user from using more secure passwords from browsers they trust?

Comment: Such stuff was the reason because I wrote a Userscript who removed autocomplete from all forms, hence its my decision if i want to save a password and not the websites owner. Not able to save the password tends to more short & insecure passwords from the users, so its bad practice and thanks god browsers ignore this nowadays

Comment: Hey @Richlv, the password manager stores the password in plain text.  We want to avoid that.

Comment: That seems wrong - many password managers today use an encrypted storage. In any case, that is not something you should attempt to control - that is a client side decision, and it should be controlled by the owner of the device.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Browser's normally have two related yet different features regarding forms:

- Form auto-complete, where items of `<input type="text">` type (and similar) collect typed values and offer them back in the form of a drop-down list.
  *(It's a simple feature that works pretty well.)*
- Password manager, where browser prompts to remember username/password combinations when it detects you've submitted a login form. When returning to the site, most browsers display available usernames in a drop-down box (Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer...) but some have a toolbar button (Opera). Also, Chrome highlights the fields in hard-coded yellow.

  *(This depends on heuristics and might fail on certain pages.)*

There's an edge case with forms tagged as `autocomplete="off"`. What happens if it's a login form and the user has previously stored a username/password? Actually *removing* the password from the local database looks like inappropriate so probably no browser does so. (In fact, data from form auto-complete is not erased either.) Firefox decides to give power to the user: you have a password, so I'll let you use it. Chrome decides to give power to the site.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent chrome from displaying suggestions in dropdown list?

Comment: @ElKopyto not really. What you can do is to trick Chrome and name your `input` other then `email`  ‍♂️

Answer (score 68):

You can just make the field readonly while form loading. While the field get focus you can change that field to be editable. This is simplest way to avoid auto complete.

```
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
```

Comment: @Nishant Pandya & Jean Paul Ruiz if you disable javascript in your browser, it wont' work

Comment: @attofi no it doesn't, it takes "false" and "new-password" as well

Comment: autocomplete="off" works for me with the above solution

Comment: @Jeff Johny The old passwords will remain the browser. If you clear your browser data, then this problem won't occur

Comment: false is not correct i think, but the readonly solution is nice and elegant

Comment: If the user double clicks on the field then the list of options will come back...

Answer (score 39):

When I faced the same problem I resolved by creating a temporary text box above the password field and hide it

like this,

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
    <ul class="field-set">
    <li>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="acct" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" style="display:none;">
        <input type="password" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" >
    </li>
        ...
    </ul> </form>
```

It will make the `username` text field not to show any previously typed words in a drop down. Since there is no attribute like `name`, `id` for the input field `<input type="text" style="display:none;">` it wouldn't send any extra parameters also.

I am Not sure this is a good practice, but it will resolve the issue.

Comment: I tried many solutions and wasted about two hours.Your trick worked!Keep up the good work friend:-)

Comment: And it seems to be broken again in Firefox 39.0.3 - it still autofills password field :( But adding `<input type="password" style="display:none">` does help :)

Comment: So frustrating to have to do these type of "hacks" to prevent autofilling. what is the actual use of `autocomplete="off"` now? Thank you though your solution helped!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a security flaw. password fields have a special protection from the browser. For a hidden text field - a User just has to use the browsers' developer tools to access that field.

Answer (score 37):

**This will prevent the auto-filling of password into the input field's (type="password").**

```
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
</form>
```

Comment: Correct. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields) _support for this value has not been implemented on Firefox_.

Comment: And after submit, all password managers will try to update the current password to the value from this input. Not suitable for the "current password" input.

Answer (score 25):

Just add the `autocomplete="new-password"` attribute to your password input field.

To learn more about `autocomplete`:

- [WHATWG HTML Standard docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-new-password)
- [Mozilla Developer Network docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: This one worked for me in 2020. Thanks for the practical answer.

Comment: @Nikz I still use it in 2022. I can appreciate when some features do not change every six months :)

Comment: This results in other potentially unwanted behavior like password helpers popping up on the field

Comment: This is not working in Chrome in 2022.

Comment: THIS JUST WORKS

Comment: not working in chrome and firefox browsers

Comment: Working on chrome 107.0.5304.107

Answer (score 14):

For text type use `autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete="false"`

```
<input id="username" type="text" autocomplete="false">
```

For password type use `autocomplete="new-password"`

```
<input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Answer (score 7):

I've tried all sort of workarounds, but just that combination worked on all browsers in my case:

```
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" 
       autocomplete="new-password" 
       onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');" 
       onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" readonly>
```

And it's quite clean solution too :)

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me, was use autocomplete="new-password" only in input type="password", like this:

```
<input id="username" type="text">
<input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Independently of how many input have the form.

Answer (score 5):

`autocomplete=off` is largely ignored in modern browsers - primarily due to password managers etc.

You can try adding this `autocomplete="new-password"` it's not fully supported by all browsers, but it works on some

```html
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
    <ul class="field-set">
    <li>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="acct" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" style="display:none;">
        <input type="password" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" autocomplete="new-password">
    </li>
        ...
    </ul> </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding `autocomplete="off"` is not gonna cut it - it's ignored by Chrome.

Change input type attribute to `type="search"`.
Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Comment: This is the only thing will prevent the autocomplete on my form with Edge Version 91.0.864.71 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: It's works on Edge :)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting autocomplete="new-password" as shown below:

```
<input type="password" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

Comment: This seems to be the first answer using the solution that worked for me. All I had to do was change autocomplete="off" to autocomplete="new-password", and it fixed both populating the password field AND populating the field above it with the my user id (email address)! I wasted two days debugging my pages, the router, the accounts authorization, etc. Very frustrating, but this solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

use this simple code

```
<input type="password" class="form-control ltr auto-complete-off" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Answer (score 3):

I was recently faced with this problem, and with no simple solution since my fields can be prepopulated, I wanted to share an elegant hack I came up with by setting password type in the ready event.

Don't declare your input field as type password when creating it, but add a ready event listener to add it for you with jQuery:

```
<input type="text" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" >

<script>
$(function(){
    document.getElementById('password').setAttribute('type', 'password');
});
</script>
```

Comment: $('#password').attr('type','password');

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hack that seems to work in Firefox and Chrome.

In Firefox, having a disabled text field just before the password field seems to do the trick, even if it is hidden (disabled: none)

In Chrome, it **has** to be visible though.

So I suggest something like this :

HTML:

```
<input class="password-autocomplete-disabler" type="text" disabled>
<input type="password" name="pwd">
```

CSS :

```
input[type=text].password-autocomplete-disabler {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -10000px !important;
    top: -10000px !important;
}
```

Comment: No idea why this works but this made my day! I just made mine `display:none`

Comment: display:none doesn't seem to work with chrome, unless you use readonly instead of disabled.

Comment: Another solution is to use "hidden": <input hidden readonly> seems to do the trick in both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but browsers have been changing over time. Although some of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606236/5150013) to this question mentioned here like: creating a temporary text box above the password field and hiding it may have worked in the past, currently the easiest way to prevent the browser from popping up the password manager is to have at least three separate additional hidden password inputs, each with different dummy values, like so:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
    <ul class="field-set">
    <li>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="acct" id="username" maxlength="100" size="20">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pswd" id="password" maxlength="16" size="20" >
        <input type="password" style="display: none;" value="dummyinput1"/>
        <input type="password" style="display: none;" value="dummyinput2"/>
        <input type="password" style="display: none;" value="dummyinput3"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" id="Login" name="Login">
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution inspired here goes as follows:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" style="position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -10000px !important;">
    <input type="password" style="position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -10000px !important;">
    Username: <input type="text">
    Password: <input type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It sure is ugly, feels misplaced in 2017, but it works and protects the username and password field from autofilling. Note that in Firefox (version 51 at the time of writing) it does not matter a bit what combination of `name`, `id` or `autocomplete` is used, be it on form or input fields. Without the first two dummy fields, autofilling will take place any time domain is matched and it will ruin your day.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Here you go.

Answer (score 3):

**You should absolutely not do this**

By disallowing and interfering with password completion you are making your users less safe. The correct coding for a password field should include:

```
autocomplete="current-password"
```

Making a user type a password means that that they have to use a weak password that they can accurately type, not use a password manager and a complex, unique, and long password.
For a detailed discussion on this see: https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/blog-post/let-them-paste-passwords

Answer (score 3):

When I faced the same problem, I came across two methods to solve it.

1. Using javascript
2. Using html (by creating a temporary text box above the password field and hide it)

Example using javascript

```
<input onfocus="this.type='password'" onblur="if (this.value.length <= 0) { this.type = 'text' } else { }" id="password"/>
```

Example using html (by creating a temporary text box just above the password field and hide it)

```
  <input type="text" style="display:none;">
  <input id="password" type="password">
```

Answer (score 2):

Why Don't Everyone Use This....

```
        <form>
            <div class="user">
            <i> </i>
            <input type="text" id="u1" name="u1" value="User Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'User Name';}">       
            </div>          
            <div class="user1"> 
            <i> </i>        
            <input type="password" id="p1" name="p1" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" >
            </div>
            <div class="user2">                         
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
```

It's So Simple... :)

Answer (score 2):

My sol :

```
<input oninput="turnOnPasswordStyle()" id="inputpassword" type="text">

function turnOnPasswordStyle(){
    $('#inputpassword').attr('type', "password");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For password , its not working currently.

So by default make password field as text and use following js code .

```js
$('#real-password').on('input', function(){
            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                $(this).attr('type', 'password');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('type', 'text');
            }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is to clean the value of the password field on page load instead of trying to prevent it from auto-filling.

With jQuery simply add something like:

```
$(function() { $('input[type="password"]').val(''); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if the input has no name (e.g. the name attribute is not set), the browser can't autocomplete the field. I know this is not a solution for everyone, but if you submit your form through AJAX, you may try this.

Comment: it is not true. I have tested this with Ajax with no name yet it was autocompleting

Comment: I've tried every combination of everything with ids. names, autocomplete and autocompleteList and nothing is preventing Edge from suggesting email addresses to populate this form.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is specific for the browser(chrome), so you can manage by adding a condition for chrome only Like:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @autocomplete = (Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower().Contains("chrome") ? "new-password" : "off") })
```

> @autocomplete = (Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower().Contains("chrome")
>   ? "new-password" : "off")

Comment: It's not Chrome specific. New Edge also has the problem, and autocomplete="new-password" fix works for it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery when click, input, or focus on the input password apply readonly and after 50 milliseconds remove readonly... effect not show drop-down list

```
window.jQuery('form input[type="password"]').on('focus input click', function(e) {
  var self = $(this);
  self.prop('readonly', true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.prop('readonly', false);
  }, 50);
});
```

Comment: Pease add some details about you code and how does it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Found Another Simple Solution and worked for me on all 3 main browsers Chrome Firefox and Opera

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='email'"/>
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='password'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution having tried other suggestions - My problem was with Edge. I tried using random string for autocomplete value and other methods suggested above but those were not solving the problem because as I later found out the problem was with the cache.

Clearing browser cache helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it:

```html
<input matInput type="text" (focus)="userNameFocus()" placeholder="Username" #u1 formControlName="userName" autocomplete="off" />

// re-initialize form on focus()

<input matInput [type]="inputType" style="-webkit-text-security: square;" #p2 formControlName="password" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. If your using bootstraps just add `form-control` in `p` tag `class` attribute

```
 <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="password" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-9">
          <p class="input-password form-control" id="password" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

And and some styling into it

```
<style>
     @font-face {
        font-family: 'password';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf');
        /* src: url("js/password/password.ttf"); */
    }

    p.input-password {
        font-family: 'password';
    }
</style>
```

Solution 2. Convert `p` tag to contenteditable=true and add some styling into it.

```
 <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'password';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf');
        /* src: url("js/password/password.ttf"); */
    }

    p.input-password {
        font-family: 'password';
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
    }
  </style>



  <label for="password" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Password</label>
  <p class="input-password" id="password" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"></p>
```

Also you can copy my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8fhn3pu/)
and thanks for this wonderful [masker](https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf) by rafaelcastrocouto.

If you experience some delay on text to circle dot, the better way is to download password masker.

1. Download the Password Masker [here](https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf),
   then place it to folder path `js/password/<your-password.tff-file>`
2. remove
   `src: url('https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf');`
3. Uncomment `src: url("js/password/password.ttf");`

Answer (score -1):

```
    <input type="password" id="byLast" class="bump25" autocomplete="new-password" onclick="this.type='text'" /> )
```

This worked for me