# Autocomplete off is not working in html with chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, forms

Sometimes in my web application even I declare `form` `autocomplete` is `off` sometimes its not working and it `autocomplete` I typed in my inputs.

Can anyone know how to solved this kind of problem.I use chrome by the way.

sample of my code: sometimes its `autocompleting` my inputs even I declare turn off already..

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name">
    <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: How is this question related to mysql/php?

Comment: Go to this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306052/autocomplete-off-not-working-on-google-chrome-browser

Comment: pass the  value="" in your input tag

Comment: How do you infer that Chrome is autocompleting? How can your problem be reproduced?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name"  value="">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="age"  value="">
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple and working perfectly in all browsers.

1. Add disabled and autocomplete="off" attribute to the form fields( name, age, etc.)

   ```
   <form method="post">
     <input disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="name" name="name">
     <input disabled="disabled" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="age" name="age">
     <input type="submit" >
   </form>
   ```
2. On Page Load enable the fields after few miliseconds.

use the below JS CODE

```
function getRidOffAutocomplete(){               
    var timer = window.setTimeout( function(){
        $('.name, .age').prop('disabled',false);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }, 800);
    }

// Invoke the function
getRidOffAutocomplete();
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug - `autocomplete` isn't supported by Chrome any more. It's a design decision by their developers and you should design for it rather than attempting to work around it. See my [answer to this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884539/905).