# How to prevent form elements from pre-populating in Chrome

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, auto-populate, form-fields

I am building a Bootstrap form and the email and password form elements show with pre-populated data from some other or some earlier form login on a different site. The Chrome browser is auto-populating the form elements.

Is there an HTML attribute of method in Bootstrap to force these form elements to null or empty on page load?

**2015-10-29 -- here's the markup:**

```
      <form autocomplete="off" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="formSubmitted" type="hidden" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`autocomplete="off"`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) attribute on the `<form>` or `<input>`.

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> **autocomplete**
>
> This attribute indicates whether the value of the control can be
>   automatically completed by the browser.
>
> *off*
>  The user must explicitly enter a value into this field for every use, or the document provides its own auto-completion method;
>   the browser does not automatically complete the entry.
>
> *on*
>  The browser is allowed to automatically complete the value based on values that the user has entered during previous uses...

Also from MDN, see: [*How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Also see:

- [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12374442/3597276)
- ["AutoComplete=Off" not working on Google Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18306052/3597276)
- [autocomplete ='off' is not working when the input type is password and make the input field above it to enable autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17719174/3597276)

Comment: I did (prior to posting my OQ) -- that did not solve it. Then I moved `autocomplete="off"` to the form tag and that too did not solve it. Seems to only be a bug in Google Chrome. Unless I am l missing something.

Comment: Ok, must be a bug on Google Chrome (latest/greatest) that we must live with then.

Comment: Answer revised with Chrome troubleshooting.

Comment: Ok, so it is a Chrome bug then.

Comment: You can call it a *bug*, but it's more likely deliberate behavior as Google may view `autocomplete="off"` as interfering with their preferred user-experience. They just choose to ignore it, just like they would probably ignore a `body` attribute named `ads="off"`.

Comment: making Chrome _non-standards_ (like the days of IE)

Comment: Actually, following their own path with IE was a completely intentional strategy by Microsoft. They called it [***Embrace, Extend and Extinguish***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish).

Comment: This solution does not work on modern browsers. Chrome just ignores "autocomplete" attribute

Comment: Use this  autocomplete="new-password"   See my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Use autocomplete="new-password"

Works a charm!

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me, and should be the accepted answer. thanks!

Comment: Agree this should be the accepted answer.