# How to remove auto suggestion from an input tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I need someone to please tell me how to remove this auto-suggested text below the input field. I have tried `autocomplete="off"` , `autocomplete="false"`. I've also placed `<form autocomplete="off"></form>` in form tag.

Anyone with a solution please help.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="label">Enter Postal Code</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type postal code ..." required>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: see image here]

Comment: Make sure that you've spelt `autocomplete` correctly, but also look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values. It says that it may not even work in some browsers. --- Also put the attribute on the input, not the form

Comment: please see image

Comment: Can you please share your HTML?

Comment: Please also share a text-based [mcve]?

Comment: html added, please check

Comment: Doing some of my own testing shows that `on` works when the input has a name attribute, and that `off` turns it off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)

Comment: `type="text"` to `type="search"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24884539/13983399

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see which browsers support the autofill attribute [CaniUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=autofill). Here is a simple work around from this source: [Turning off form-autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion).

You can work around with `autofill="new-password"`

"If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent autofilling of password fields, you can use autocomplete="new-password"."

```html
<form method="post" action="/form">
  <div>
    <label for="cc">Enter Postal Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cc" name="cc" autocomplete="new-password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Lastly, instead of pairing a `<span>` with the input element, it is common practice to use the `<label>` element. Please read more here [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Answer (score 0):

Apply autocomplete="off" to your form not the input box.