# auto complete is not working in firefox 38

Tags: html, firefox

I have a profile form in my site in which the password field is auto filled even after i gave auto complete="off" to the text box and also to the form. After that also i got the password field auto complete.

```
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try this instead of using any dummy hidden variables within the form.

```
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
```

Answer (score 2):

At last i found a solution for this question. We can make the field as read only and editable on getting focus.

```
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting hack (and some good explanations) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719174/autocomplete-off-is-not-working-when-the-input-type-is-password-and-make-the) answer:

Basically you add an extra input field to confuse the browser.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found a solution for the same and share below. Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

**Autocomplete doesn't work on any forms**

If you find that Firefox will not save any text you enter into forms, follow the instructions below.

**Check Firefox settings**
Make sure that Firefox is set to remember form entries and that saved form entries are not being automatically cleared:

Click the menu button  New Fx Menu and choose Options.

Select the Privacy panel.

Set Firefox will: to Use custom settings for history.

Make sure that Remember search and form history is selected.

Enabling form autocomplete also makes Firefox store search history for the Search bar.

Find Clear history when Firefox closes. If it is selected:

Click on the Settings... button.

Make sure that Form & Search History is not selected.

Click OK.

Close the about:preferences page.

**[REFERENCE](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-doesnt-save-web-form-entries)**

Comment: this one is useful only if we are checking locally. How can we know whether the user who is seeing the site will do the same in the setting? It is not possible. So i am looking for code to fix this in the form code itself.