# Autocomplete/fill not turning off

Tags: html, css

On my site I have many forms, some of which I do not want browsers to autocomplete/fill.

I have tried adding `autocomplete="off"` on all imputs which I don't want to be completed/filled.

This appears to be the standard method but I cannot seem to find any others, is there another way to do this?

Thanks

```
        <label>First Name:</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['fname']); ?>" /><br />
        <label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['lname']); ?>" /><br />
        <label>Email:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?php echo ($userRow['email']); ?>" /><br />
```

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this issue on? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719174/autocomplete-off-is-not-working-when-the-input-type-is-password-and-make-the

Comment: I didn't suggest anything...

Comment: Does it not seem simple?  The autocomplete is set to off, it still completes...

Comment: @DanielMinett the issue is a known browser compatibility problem for a long time, it would be best if you provided more detail as to how you are testing your code, which browser, etc

Comment: @AGE the page is being tested using latest chrome build.

Comment: As far as I understand, Chrome 34+, Firefox 38+ and IE11+ have issues with this.

Comment: Is there another method you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature which changed on Chrome [not long ago](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en), you can find a solution after looking through Google's Chrome Help Forum the way I did:

> 1. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> 2. Select Settings.
> 3. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Passwords and forms" section.
> 4. Deselect the "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click" checkbox.
> 5. Lastly, if you are want to get rid of predictions in the address bar in Chrome, you can learn how to disable that feature.

If this helped then fantastic, otherwise I highly recommend you make a request at: [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome).

Also **very important** your forms will change as Chrome/other browsers change, so it matters to keep in touch with the latest changes if you are looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: This would have to be done on everyone's PC.  As it's a website, it would be globally accessible, so not a viable option.

Comment: sadly true, but according to https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/106230?hl=en there's little we can do about it

Comment: Thank you for the answer anyway

Comment: No problem @DanielMinett, try asking Google Help Forum I bet they can be more specific about how to get around this issue... but so far all I read is complaints on how this feature is no longer up to the programmer's control