# autocomplete false is not working in the input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing issue with autocomplete false. Can anyone please give the best solution for it?

current html:

```
<form name="register" action=""  method="">
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Username" name="email" autocomplete="false">
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="false" required>
<div id="submit" type="submit">Let me in!</div>
</form>
```

Comment: <form name="register" action=""  method="">
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Username" name="email" autocomplete="false">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" autocomplete="false" required>
        <div id="submit" type="submit">Let me in!</div>
    </form>

Comment: Here is my html code for the login form

Comment: `<form name="..." action=".." autocomplete="off">...</form>` this will do the trick

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: @sandip autocomplete will not work in password form field please check this for more detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719174/autocomplete-off-is-not-working-when-the-input-type-is-password-and-make-the

Comment: @sandip soultion is `<input name="password" id="password" type="password" autocomplete="false" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" />`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all autocomplete from input fields and add:

`<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">` in replacement of your initial `<form>` tag

This will disable the autocomplete completely on the form.

Comment: I want blank fields When i logged out from the page and return back to login page. When i back to login page the details already filled in the input boxes.

Comment: They won't be blank if you have automatically saved the input fields to your browser. This code will 100% work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is a glitch where it autocomplete on the last input field.

A simple trick is to add input text field with:

```
style="display: none;"
```

as the last input field.