# Vulnerability : Password type input with auto-complete enabled

Tags: html, css, security

- I have added autocomplete="off" and also i tried autocomplete="new-password" to the password texfield

---

```
<input type="password" name="login[password]" id="login_password" placeholder="Password" data-validate="not-empty" data-validate-error-message-position="below">
```

- Already saved Password autocomplete is coming in chrome and firefox which should not come and if i use autocomplete="off" or autocomplete="new-password" in input field. I need solution to fix this Vulnerability. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it really vulnerability? If you choose to not store passwords, you won't get this problem. So it is user choice, not vulnerability

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719174/autocomplete-off-is-not-working-when-the-input-type-is-password-and-make-the.

Comment: Yes its a vulnerability. I think we can store your passwords but autocomplete should not come for password fields

Comment: @Trollsyn : Its a duplicate but there is no solution there

Comment: @SivaShanker so what is the point of storing passwords in browser then if it doesn't make it easy to fill the form? :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the major browsers now ignore autocomplete=off.

For more info check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields)

You can add hidden input has type password

```
  <input type="text" style="display:none">
  <input type="password" style="display:none">
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, will this resolve the Vulnerability, pls suggest?

Comment: It will not prevent browser from auto complete password fields, you can't prevent this, but in this case the browser will auto complete the hidden password fields, and make sure that two hidden fields come before your input fields.

Comment: another solution, you can prevent browser from saving password and auto complete it by change password input type and name to not be equal password.

Comment: please verify against FireFox, Chrome and IOS i hope one of the browser your solution wont work

Answer (score 0):

We recently faced this issue, to overcome this we did some trick will explain below,

Problem,

We faced issue with save password modal is appearing when doing login (post successful), note we are not using inside

Solution

1. We keep this `<input type="password" autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" />` as its
2. Using CSS we will apply password type (dot) behaviour

mask the text and will show the password type dot

```
    font-family: "text-security-disc";   
    text-security: disc;  
    -webkit-text-security: disc !important;  
    -mox-text-security: disc;
```

3. Before submit(first step of submit before making ajax call) we will change the type of the input to "text" so that browser will not understand and wont prompt the user. also as you mapped password using CSS you cant able to see in the UI even if you change the type.